Output of Mail App's Save As Raw Message Source on emails is invalid HTML
When I save the email as Raw Message Source many tags are broken by some kind of weird encoding. Is this intentional? For example, meta tags that should look like this:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
Instead look like this:
<meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=3D=
1">

Notice the unnecessary line break and the additional 3D. Also, there is output like this throughout the file where = are added at the point of line breaks from the output:
<body style=3D"font-family: Inter, Helvetica, Arial; color: #192436; word-s=
pacing: normal; background-color: #F5F6F8;">
  <div style=3D"background-color:#F5F6F8;" lang=3D"en">
    <!--[if mso | IE]><table align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0=
" cellspacing=3D"0" class=3D"" role=3D"presentation" style=3D"width:632px;"=
 width=3D"632" ><tr><td style=3D"line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-hei=
ght-rule:exactly;"><![endif]-->

I expected the output to be valid HTML I could view in the browser (I want to debug a CSS issue and apparently cannot turn on dev tools within the Mail app).

When I save the email as Raw Message Source many tags are broken by some kind of weird encoding. Is this intentional?
Yes, it is intentional.
To support different languages, MIME encodes messages with either Base64 (which is not human-readable) or the fairly readable Q-encoding, used in the excerpt you provide in your question.
Q-encoding (which is a slightly modified version of Quoted-Printable)
encodes characters other than printable ASCII characters with the following sequence for each byte of the UTF-8 representation of that character:

an equal sign (=)
two digits that represent the byte's hexadecimal value

For example, the a with umlaut character (ä) is represented by =C3=A4, and an ASCII form feed character is represented by =0C.
Since = is used as an escape character, it needs to be encoded, too. Its representation is =3D, that's why =3Dappears where=` would be expected in the HTML text.
The additional line breaks are a consequence of the requirement that lines of Quoted-Printable-encoded text should not be longer than 76 characters. To satisfy this limitation, soft line breaks consisting of a = at the end of an encoded line are added.

I expected the output to be valid HTML I could view in the browser.
After "decoding" the Quoted-Printable-encoded text, it should indeed be valid HTML markup and CSS, but note that its correctness and completeness depends on the email client that composed the message.
I can confirm that some email clients send HTML that can be viewed in a browser, while others use a subset of HTML.
